# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?Tried, and tried

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def half_finished_diamond(height):
    n = 1
    for i in range(height):
        spaces = height / 2 - n
        blank = " "
        print(blank*spaces + '/' * n + '\\' * n + "\n")
        n += 1


half_finished_diamond(8)
```

Wanting to get the upper part of diamond shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, when you say `space = height / 2 - n`, it automatically casts the result to a float, so `spaces` will be `4.0 - 1 = 3.0`. You'll have to cast it to an `int` to multiply a string by it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that floor division (the way Python2 handled division where both operands were integers), can still be obtained with double slashes (e.g. `x // y`).

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, since you are using Python3, you can use the floor division operator to assure an int result:

```
def half_finished_diamond(height):
    n = 1
    for i in range(height):
        spaces = height // 2 - n    # <-- note the // instead of /
        blank = " "
        print(blank*spaces + '/' * n + '\\' * n + "\n")
        n += 1


half_finished_diamond(8)
```

See it in action on https://eval.in/1078035

Comment: Thank you for your help